# Some questions about SMTP RFC

Tags: smtp, protocols, rfc

I have two questions about SMTP RFC:

- What value should I pass as the argument for the EHLO command if I don't have my own domain name?

> The domain name given in the EHLO command MUST be either a primary
>         host name (a domain name that resolves to an address RR) or, if
>         the host has no name, an address literal, as described in
>         Section 4.1.3 and discussed further in the EHLO discussion of
>         Section 4.1.4.

I don't really undesrstand Section 4.1.3. Can you give me an example or rephrase it?

- Which headers are required to send in the DATA section?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Argument to EHLO in the absence of a domain name

Section [4.1.3 Address Literals](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.1.3) of [RFC 2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821) says:

> Sometimes a host is not known to the domain name system and
> communication (and, in particular, communication to report and repair
> the error) is blocked.  To bypass this barrier a special literal form
> of the address is allowed as an alternative to a domain name.  For
> IPv4 addresses, this form uses four small decimal integers separated
> by dots and enclosed by brackets such as [123.255.37.2], which
> indicates an (IPv4) Internet Address in sequence-of-octets form.

so a simple `EHLO [123.255.37.2]` suffices (with the actual IP address of your SMTP server of course). Or it could be a properly formatted IPv6 instead.

#### Required headers

Section [3.6. Field definitions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6) of [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) says:

> The only required header fields are the origination date field and
> the originator address field(s).  All other header fields are
> syntactically optional.

so only `From:` and `Date:` are required.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a domain name, you should use your IP address:

```
EHLO [192.168.1.1]
```

It's kind of a ridiculous requirement in the protocol seeing as how there's no real value in this piece of information. The server shouldn't trust it (obviously) and it is trivial for the server to get the IP address of the connecting client, anyway.